# How to determine the correct position of an Image inside of a CTabItem

Tags: java, swt, tooltip, ctabitem

I add some `CTabItem`s with `Image`s to a `CTabFolder`:

```
CTabFolder tabFolder = new CTabFolder(someSection, SWT.BORDER);
ImageDescriptor deleteImageDesc = sharedImages.getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_ETOOL_DELETE);
Image deleteImage = deleteImageDesc.createImage();
CTabItem tabItem = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
tabItem.setImage(deleteImage);
// add more tabs...
```

[image: tabItems]

Then I want to create a `ToolTip` which appears if user moves mouse over a `deleteImage`.

```
ToolTip deleteToolTip = new ToolTip(getShell(), SWT.BALOON);
deleteToolTip.setMessage("Delete");
tabFolder.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseHover(MouseEvent e)
    {
        toolTip.setLocation(tabFolder.toDisplay(e.x, e.y));
        toolTip.setVisible(doesAnyOfTabImagesContainPoint(mousePosition));
    }
});
```

To implement method `doesAnyOfTabImagesContainPoint` I need to determine the position of every `deleteImage`. Since `CTabItem` isn't a `Control` I cannot use method `toDisplay`. I try to solve this by manually determining the position of `deleteImage` relative to `tabFolder`. It would help because the mouse position held by `MouseEvent` is also relative to `tabFolder`.

```
private boolean doesAnyOfTabImagesContainPoint(Point p)
{
    for (CTabItem tabItem : tabFolder.getItems())
    {
        Image i = tabItem.getImage();
        Rectangle tabItemBounds = tabItem.getBounds();
        Rectangle imageBounds = i.getBounds();
        imageBounds.x += tabItemBounds.x;
        imageBounds.y += tabItemBounds.y;
        if (imageBounds.contains(p))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The requirement for working this properly is that `Rectangle` returned by `i.getBounds()` has correct location relative to `tabItem`. However it returns `(0, 0, 16, 16)` which cannot be right.

A dirty way to fix this would be to just add some constants:

```
imageBounds.x += bsTabBounds.x + 4;
imageBounds.y += bsTabBounds.y + 3;
```

But I am wondering if there's better way. I'm trying to investigate how `CTabFolder` positions images of the tabs but without success by now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**edit:** for testing purposes here's the extracted image which i get from `ISharedImages` modified to see its border: [image: delete.png]

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: I am glad you are interested if your solution worked for me. Sorry for the delay, I've been on vacation this week. I tested your code at home and it looks like the problem doesn't appear for the simplified example. But I need to test this in real application to make the final decision if the problem is really solved. I'll do it on Monday as soon as I get to work.

Answer (score 1):

Give the code below a shot. It's based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844190/1740724).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final TabFolder folder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);

    TabItem item = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    item.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR));
    item.setText("Text");

    folder.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, event -> {
        TabFolder curFolder = (TabFolder) event.widget;
        Point eventLocation = new Point(event.x, event.y);
        TabItem theItem = curFolder.getItem(eventLocation);

        if (theItem == null)
            return;

        Image image = theItem.getImage();

        if (eventLocation.x >= curFolder.getClientArea().x + theItem.getBounds().x + image.getBounds().x
                && eventLocation.x <= curFolder.getClientArea().x + theItem.getBounds().x + image.getBounds().x + image.getBounds().width
                && eventLocation.y >= theItem.getBounds().y + image.getBounds().y
                && eventLocation.y <= theItem.getBounds().y + image.getBounds().y + image.getBounds().height)
        {
            System.out.println("show tooltip");
        }
    });


    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

I've tested it on Windows 7 and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I adjusted my application to use your piece of code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I extracted the used image from org.eclilpse.ui and modified it to see borders. Here's a screenshot where you see that the tooltip appears where it shouldn't: http://i.imgur.com/ZT46ZHh.png

Comment: @DannyLo That's interesting. Unfortunately, I can't really see why this is happening.

Comment: I just edited my question to provide that image with border, maybe you could test it on your system.

Comment: @DannyLo I gave it a try and I just can't find a way to retrieve those magical 2 pixels that are missing. My guess is that it's the space to the "left" of the actual folder, but I'm not sure.

Comment: More curiosity: inside of my application the gap to the left is only 1 magical pixel. Vertical gap is the same: 4 pixels.

Comment: Nope, the Vertical gap is also different: 3 and 4 pixels.

Comment: @DannyLo I'm afraid you'll have to hard code those pixels in this case. Can't think of a cleaner solution I'm afraid.

Comment: I added the amount of "magical" pixels to `image.getBounds().x` and `y` and was able to observe correct behavior of the tooltip on the left and top borders. But then this happens: http://i.imgur.com/pxNWNLc.png 1 pixel too much on the bottom and right which forces me to adjust `width` and `height` of the `Rectangle` as well.

Comment: @DannyLo Or replace the `<=`s with `<`s.

Comment: I afraid that this could look messy on MacOS or *nix. Need to test it. If the magical pixels are system-dependent, then I lose.

Comment: @DannyLo Well, you can determine which OS you are running your code on and then set the pixels.

Comment: If you do this with `folder.setTabPosition(SWT.BOTTOM)` then the behavior is messed up again. I need this because I have second `tabFolder` with that style in my application which needs tooltips as well.

Comment: @DannyLo I'm really sorry, but I can't seem to be able to help you with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77510/discussion-between-danny-lo-and-baz).